# Project timeline whose events can be moved to a new date directly from the timeline (date changes according to position)

Tags: project-management, time-management

I am interesting in finding a project timeline software that has an interactive visualization of the actual timeline. This means that if the date of a certain event has moved, you can just click+hold it and slide it to the new date.

I need something that can be easily modified without having to enter/alter any text. So, instead of going to a certain event and editing the actual date, you can just move its marker further from the initial position.

I need this because the dates on my project change often and there are never 100% certain dates. This would allow us to move the marker to a 'proposed date' and keep on doing this until we have certainty.

An alternative would be a timeline software with which you can easily right click and "enter a new event". This way we could just delete and easily add a new mark on the 'proposed date'.

Do you guys know any (open source preferably, but not necessarily) project timeline software that has this type of user interaction implemented?

Comment: Online/standalone? Program, code or API (*software* is too generic)? If standalone, what OS? Budget? Number of data points/complexity of projects (i.e. hierarchies/dependencies)? What is wrong with the many project management/planning packages available? Please [edit] your question and answer **all** these questions.

Comment: Online/standalone

Comment: Online/standalone - irrelevant  
Program, code or API - all  
OS - irrelevant  
Budget - irrelevant at this point. Can't set a budget without knowing that it exists?  
Number of data points/complexity of projects - Can this be a limitation? (less than 500 data points)
What is wrong with the many project management/planning packages available? - They don't suit my needs as good as something like [Timeline](http://thetimelineproj.sourceforge.net/) as Matthew Lock suggested due to the method of editing the dates. A lot of times we just need to "push" the date without having something specific.

Comment: How difficult is reading? I even provided you an [edit] link in my comment.

Comment: No, reading is not difficult, thank you for the implied insult, but doing something without logic is.
You basically give **zero input**, ask a bunch of **irrelevant details** that would imply you have so many applicable answers to my request and on top of that insult me even though I clearly mentioned that I've received an appropriate answer from Matthew Lock.
So, how difficult is reading?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about [Timeline](http://thetimelineproj.sourceforge.net/)? It's an open source desktop application that runs on most platforms and lets you drag events to new dates, or drag their start and end dates for date ranges.

[image]